# How do you Allow the user to search for a date in a database, showing them all relevant information c#

Tags: c#, database, search

I want to allow the user to search for a specific date (using a text box) and for the database to show them all entered information within that date. I have already compiled the query, show below:

```
   SELECT Date, ([Test result]),               
   FROM [User/Test]
   WHERE Date Like '%' + @value + '%'
```

I have used a data grid view on a phone to allow the user to visually see the search, incorporated a text box and search button and I have used the code below behind this button:

```
    this.user_TestTableAdapter.search(this.questionareDataSet1._User_Test,    textBox1.Text);
```

The error I get is that a varchar can't be compared with a date, which I understand. Do I need to convert the date to string to enable the search to take place?

Thanks.

Comment: Rather than convert the date to string, I would convert your search string to a date.  That way you can avoid all of the different issues with formatting a date.

Comment: Thanks, any advice on how to do that? I am fairly new to c#

Comment: Depending on how you are compiling your query, and what type of database you are using.  But for example, in MSSQL server, your `WHERE` clause could look like this: `WHERE Date = CONVERT(DATE, @value)`

Answer (score 0):

Force formatting to a date "safe" format on the input field (look into the jQuery datepicker method for websites).

```
var selectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtInputDate.Value);
var sql = " SELECT * FROM table WHERE datefield BETWEEN '" + selectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND NOW();";
```

You can also do things like...

```
var dateAddDaysValue = 2;
var sql = " SELECT * FROM table WHERE datefield BETWEEN '" + selectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND '" + selectedDate.AddDays(dateAddDaysValue).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "';";
```

Cheerio!

Edit: You should be aware that this method of building SQL queries is extremely vulnerable to injection.  Make sure you are properly sanatizing your queries.

Comment: The query was compiled using the wizard in VS, the code behind the user search is behind a button within the form, how would I go about implementing your suggested improvements if the query is compiled via a wizard?